# Java Generic Factory

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to build a generic factory for the Mapper interface that depends on the resource class type.

Here is the code:

```
public interface Resource { }

public class IntegerResource implements Resource { }

public class IntegerMapper implements Mapper<IntegerResource> {

}

    public static <R extends Resource> Mapper<R> buildMapper(Class<R> clazz){
        if (IntegerResource.class.equals(clazz)){
            return new IntegerMapper();//Compilation error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from IntegerMapper to Mapper<R>

        }
        return null;
    }

    public <R extends Resource> R getResource(Class<R> clazz){
        Mapper<R> m = buildMapper(clazz);
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: How can I fix the compilation error at             return IntegerMapper();//Compilation error

Answer (score 4):

To build an instance of a class, you have to use the keyword `new`:

```
return new IntegerMapper();
```

Edit: the compiler is also not smart enough to know that if `clazz` is the IntegerResource class, then R represents the type IntegerResource. So you have to cast it explicitely:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <R extends Resource> Mapper<R> buildMapper(Class<R> clazz){
    if (IntegerResource.class.equals(clazz)){
        return (Mapper<R>) new IntegerMapper();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The SuppressWarning bit is there to tell the compiler that you know this cast is safe, and that it should not give a warning about it.

Comment: The compiler error is really about `IntegerMapper()` not being a function, because it is a constructor, so you need to call it with `new IntegerMapper()` to get a class back.

Comment: the new is no help. I forgot to add it to the snippet. The actual compilation error is : Type mismatch: cannot convert from IntegerMapper to Mapper<R>

Comment: It s an option, I was hoping to have a clean implementation generics without use of  SuppressWarnings

Comment: And funny, your solution doesn't compile outside eclipse on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode), error: inconvertible types